# Waiting for all async downloads to complete

Tags: c#, asynchronous, download

I'm trying to run some code that downloads multiple files, and waiting for all to be completed before continuing with the code execution.

I currently have this part of code running, which actually does download everything as it's supposed to, but it won't resume the execution.. The program just freezes.

Would be great if you could help me with resolving this, thanks.

```
private void DownloadFiles(string[] targets, string sub_id, string base_url)
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    int c = 0;

    foreach (var target in targets)
    {
        if (target.EndsWith(".vtt", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            using (var wc = new WebClient())
            {
                var task = DownloadFile(wc, base_url + sub_id + "/" + target, sub_id + "." + c++ + ".vtt");
                tasks.Add(task);
            }
        }
    }
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}


private Task DownloadFile(WebClient wc, string target, string name)
{
    wc.DownloadProgressChanged += (object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ProgressPercentage + "% downloaded.");
    };

    wc.DownloadFileCompleted += (object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(target + " was downloaded.");
    };

    return wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(target, Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/Subs/" + name);
}
```

Comment: Try changing the `using (var wc = new WebClient())` to `var wc = new WebClient();` and see if the problem goes away. Let me know.

Comment: @Enigmativity Hey, I tried your suggestion, though it seems to have the same behavior of downloading everything but still frozen

Comment: Be careful with `WebClient` and `HttpClient` --the latter is `IDisposable` and should be handled carefully to avoid socket exhaustion.

Comment: @clarkitect I'm not using `HttpClient`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive` and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` - then you can do this:

```
var query =
    from x in targets.ToObservable().Select((t, c) => new { t, c })
    where x.t.EndsWith(".vtt", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
    let target = $"{base_url}{sub_id}/{x.t}"
    let name = $"{sub_id}.{x.c}.vtt"
    from status in
        Observable
            .Using(
                () => new WebClient(),
                wc =>
                {
                    var progress =
                        Observable
                            .FromEventPattern<DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs>(
                                h => wc.DownloadProgressChanged += h, h => wc.DownloadProgressChanged -= h)
                            .Select(ep => $"{ep.EventArgs.ProgressPercentage}% downloaded.");

                    var completed =
                        Observable
                            .FromAsync(() => wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(target, $"{Environment.CurrentDirectory}/Subs/{name}"))
                            .Select(z => $"{target} was downloaded.");

                    return progress.Merge(completed);
                })
    select new { target, status };
```

That's one asynchronous query that handles all of the parallel calls - disposing the `WebClient` as it finishes each call.

You can get it to wait for all of the results like this:

```
query
    .Do(x => Console.WriteLine(x.status))
    .ToArray()
    .Wait();
```

But the more idiomatic way to handle it is this:

```
IDisposable subscription =
    query
        .Subscribe(
            x => Console.WriteLine(x.status),
            ex => { /* handle an exception */ },
            () => { /* when everything is done */ });
```

This processes the results as soon as they are available and gives you a chance to run some code when you're done.

If you need to marshall to a UI thread then you can do this:

```
IDisposable subscription =
    query
        .ObserveOnDispatcher() // or .ObserveOn(instanceOfForm)
        .Subscribe(
            x => Console.WriteLine(x.status),
            ex => { /* handle an exception */ },
            () => { /* when everything is done */ });
```

To stop the download in case you need to stop early just do `subscription.Dispose();`.

Comment: I'm gonna need to update my VS and NuGet for it. I'll keep you posted, thanks!

Comment: Hey, I tried your code and it seems to download everything in 2 seconds, but it takes about 30 seconds until it actually continues the code (and I also made it show a MessageBox when done, but I never get it before the code continues)

Comment: @Aradmey - Can you show me the code? Perhaps on https://dotnetfiddle.net

Comment: @Aradmey - As much as is needed to see the results you're seeing.

Comment: I don't think I can post a Winfoms in there.. Can I send you a pastebin?

Comment: @Aradmey - Whatever it takes to show me what you're getting.

Comment: Why do you have `WebClient client = new WebClient();` and then `using (client)`?

Comment: I removed the `using (client)` part, though it's not the async part. Could it be delaying with the response because I run it on my UI..?

Comment: You have way too much going on in that click event. You need to learn to refactor things out. If the method goes longer than one screen height then you've got too much code in the one method.

Comment: @Aradmey - No, the `using` won't do that. It just seems odd to code it that way.

Comment: But running the code will freeze the UI for about 30 seconds until it shows message "Done2" although it finished downloading in 2 seconds as I could see the files

Comment: I commented out `x => Console.WriteLine(x.status)` and it actually made the program run much faster, showing the "Done2" message in 1-2 seconds. Though, I think it resumes the code without waiting for the downloads to complete.

Comment: @Aradmey - It seems, maybe, that you've over optimized this. A simple linear `async`/`await` solution might be more than suitable in this case. Have you thought of doing that?

Comment: Sorry I haven't replied in a while, though I have re-written the whole code while using backgroundWorker which works wonder with your provided code.
Although, I still have one question. Is it faster to download all links to files and then reading them, or downloading them straight to one huge array?

Comment: @Aradmey - Try both ways and time it. That's always the best way to know.

Comment: Also, how do I check the exception in your `IDisposable` code? I tried counting the errors, but it gets to about 3,000 instead of only 1 that should really be the error.

Comment: I checked now, and each file that fails to download won't run this exception handling code.

Comment: @Aradmey - I'd have to write code to run and test this properly. You should only ever get one error with an observable. It immediately stops running the rest on error. There are ways to get observables to retry in the case of errors or to ignore and keep running. But I'd need to know exactly what errors you're facing and where to help fix it.

Answer (score 1):

### tl;dr

You'll want to `await` tasks and `async` methods

```
await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
// ...
return await wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(...);
```

This assumes a method with an `async` signature.

### ok but why?

Setting aside the possibility that these void methods are event handlers --running on a UI thread in winforms, webforms, wpf, whatever-- your `WaitAll` is a *blocking* method.  By waiting for all of those you are blocking the current thread.  By *awaiting* all of those, you're allowing them to be run asynchronously.

If these void methods are also being run on the UI thread then that's a second, and similar, problem.

### a longer example

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

/// <summary>
/// Await all files in a list of paths to download
/// </summary>
public async Task DownloadFilesAsync(IWebClient client, IEnumerable<string> filePaths) 
{
    var downloadTasks = filePaths
        .Select(f => DownloadFileAsync(client, f))
        .ToArray();

    // if any fails, we return that an error occurred.  If you prefer to let "some" of
    // those downloads fail, just move the try/catch into the individual file download 
    // method below.
    try {
        // wait for all to complete
        await Task
            .WhenAll(downloadTasks)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // I just made this up as an example; find the right type 
        // of result using intellisense in your IDE
        return Task.ErroredTask(e);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Await a single file download
/// </summary>
public async Task DownloadFileTaskAsync(IWebClient client, string filePath) 
{
    // set up request in the client, etc
    var url = "http://example.com";

    return await client
        .DownloadFile(url, filePath)
        .ConfigureAwait(false);

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried doing what you said, but it's not working, errors popping up.

Comment: @Aradmey describe the errors. Dont assume we know what you got.

Comment: You'll get compile errors if you try to use the `await` keyword in a method that doesn't have the `async` signature.

Comment: @clarkitect I don't really have any knowledge whatsoever about async. That's why I don't know what to add where. I was hoping you could show me an example using my code if that's okay with you.